# I want to change the 'startbutton.href = " " ' based on the changing img.src. the if esle statement does not work

Tags: javascript

```
let index = 1;
let images = [
    './img/wok.jpg',
    './img/croissant.jpg',
    './img/salad.jpg'
];

let img = document.getElementById("section-1-img");
let startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

setInterval(function() {
    img.src = images[index];
    index = (index +1) % images.length;
    
    if (img.src === './img/wok.jpg') {
        startButton.href = 'recipe.html';
    else if (img.src === './img/croissant.jpg') { 
        startButton.href = 'recipe-2.html';
    else if (img.src === './img/salad.jpg') { 
        startButton.href = 'recipe-3.html';
} 2000);
```

i want that the button.href be changed based on the img.src. so if i click on that button, that it sends me to the right html.page

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind formatting your code with backticks `\``?

Comment: If you checked the browser's debugger, you would see that there are syntax errors in your code. You forgot to close your `if` blocks with a curly brace, and there is a comma missing between the callback function and the number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

best option would be to create an array with objects, containing the image and the href. this will eliminate the `if-else` conditions and you have your data set at one place.

the starting index of an array is btw `0` and not `1`.

```js
let index = 0; // starting at 0

// the data (previously images), containing objects
const data = [
  { img: './img/wok.jpg', href: 'recipe.html' },
  { img: './img/croissant.jpg', href: 'recipe-2.html' },
  { img: './img/salad.jpg', href: 'recipe-3.html' },
];

const img = document.getElementById("section-1-img");
const startButton = document.getElementById('startButton');

setInterval(function() {
  img.src = data[index].img;
  startButton.href = data[index].href

  // update index after or before the previous calls, depends what u want
  index = (index + 1) % data.length;
} 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your if statements, this code should work

```
if (img.src === './img/wok.jpg') {
    startButton.href = 'recipe.html';
}
else if (img.src === './img/croissant.jpg') { 
    startButton.href = 'recipe-2.html';  
}
else if (img.src === './img/salad.jpg') { 
    startButton.href = 'recipe-3.html'; 
}
```